# Imported python file with relative path inside

Tags: python, import, relative-path, subdirectory, os.path

I have a problem with relative paths in my python 2.7 project. I have two files, let's call them script.py and importedScript.py, which have different directories, because importedScript is in a subfolder.
importedScript.py has a method called openCSV(), which gets imported in script.py with

```
from subfolder.importedScript import openCSV
```

This works fine. The method openCSV(filename) has the following code inside:

```
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
filepath = os.path.join(script_path, 'subfolder2/' + filename)
dataset = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

This code imports a  .csv file from a subfolder. This works also fine, if I run the importedScript.py by itself.

The problem now is, that when I run script.py, the relative path in  importedScript.py is generated wrong. For some reasons, the system tries to load the importedScript.py from "subfolder2/" instead of "subfolder/subfolder2".

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: In subfolder2 are different .csv files and I want to open different files from different python files.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the `__file__` variable to the method on call:

```
def OpenCSV(file):
    here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))
    ...etc
```

can be called by doing `OpenCSV(__file__)`

Comment: openCSV gets the filename as parameter, but i cannot see how giving the path as an input parameter shall fix my problem. Because the given path will be the path of the script.py file and then the join path will be wrong again. Or am I thinking wrong? I dont want to produce the path in script.py, because I want to use the subscript in other files as well.

Comment: have you tried this ? the __file__ isn't a path it's a variable representing the current script that's being executed